# Load Bitmap with AsyncTask onPostLoad

Tags: android, button, android-asynctask, progress-bar, visibility

I have a set of buttons and i want them to be visible only when the image is loaded..and the progressbar to hide,how can i do that..whenever use onPreExecute() or write

```
 buttonname.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

in post execute it stops loading the image..Here is what i am using..please help me out i am stuck

```
    public class Main extends Activity{

    ImageView image,next,back;
    Button a;
    static int fullWidth;
    static int fullHeight;
     ProgressBar progressbar;
     Button setWallpaper;


     private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Bitmap> {
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String...url) {
                //--- download an image ---
               Bitmap bitmap = DownloadImage(url[0]);
                return bitmap;
            }
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {

                ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                bitmaptwo=bitmap;
                image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);


            }
        }
    private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString)
    throws IOException
    {InputStream in = null;
    int response= -1;
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
   if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection ))
   throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
    try{
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect();
        response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            in = httpConn.getInputStream();
        }
        }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new IOException("Error connecting");
    }
    return in;
    }
    private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            in.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e1){
            Toast.makeText(this,e1.getLocalizedMessage(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
    public static Bitmap bitmaptwo;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try
        {
        new BackgroundTask().execute("http://meluha.in/wp-content/uploads/1.jpg");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        setWallpaper = (Button) findViewById(R.id.abcd);
        ImageView next = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.next);
        ImageView back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.back);


        setWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                WallpaperManager wManager;

                try {

                //  Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView1.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    wManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                    fullWidth = wManager.getDesiredMinimumWidth();
                    fullHeight = wManager.getDesiredMinimumHeight(); 
                    Bitmap bitmapResized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmaptwo, fullWidth, fullHeight,true);
                    wManager.setBitmap(bitmapResized);


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code yo your `onPostExecute` method:

```
button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//....
progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: Can you add the code you're using to call the task? And the full task code (If the one here isn't full)

Comment: the full code would be a huge one..ok i'll edit in my question

Comment: Its working fine as it is..but what i want is that the setWallpaper and the back,next button are visible only when the image has been loaded..so i've set visibility as "Gone" in XML and when i use

back.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

in the onPostExecute() it crashes

Comment: I don't think you should use `GONE`. `View.GONE` means the view doesn't take any space when calculating the layout, and it may cause problems when you make it visible again after the layout was already calculated. Try setting it as `INVISIBLE` in your XML file. Anyway, check what the error log says when it crashes.

Comment: I am testing it n my phone the emulator is not working..i'll just check whether using Invisible instead of Gone works or not

Comment: You can download your phone logs when connecting the device to your computer, using the `adb logcat` command. Read more here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html Check the error in the logs